# HTML Email not displaying an image

Tags: html, css, html-email

We're using Emailify to export Figma designs to HTML. Once imported 3 out of the 5 emails are working as intended but the other 2 are not showing the main image, just the text without it.

This is one of the exported codes we got.

I'm pretty lost since we're not doing anything different.

```
               <!--[if mso | IE]>
</td></tr></table>
<![endif]-->
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <!--[if mso | IE]>
</td></tr></table>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="r-outlook -outlook pr-16-outlook pl-16-outlook -outlook" role="presentation" style="width:600px;" width="600"><tr><td style="line-height:0;font-size:0;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">
<![endif]-->
      <div class="r  pr-16 pl-16" style="background:#fffffe;background-color:#fffffe;margin:0px auto;max-width:600px;">
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background:#fffffe;background-color:#fffffe;width:100%;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="border:none;direction:ltr;font-size:0;padding:48px 22px 44px 31px;text-align:center;">

                <!--[if mso | IE]>
<table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td class="c-outlook -outlook -outlook" style="vertical-align:middle;width:546px;">
<![endif]-->
                <div class="xc546 ogf c" style="font-size:0;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;width:100%;">
                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:none;vertical-align:middle;" width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" class="x " style="font-size:0;word-break:break-word;">
                          <div style="text-align:center;">
                            <p style="Margin:0;text-align:center;mso-line-height-alt:24px;mso-ansi-font-size:22px;"><span style="font-size:21px;font-family:Montserrat,Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:700;color:#181d5b;line-height:114%;mso-line-height-alt:24px;mso-ansi-font-size:22px;">Estamos emocionados por la posibilidad de ser parte de tu viaje educativo. No importa d&oacute;nde te encuentres en tu decisi&oacute;n, estamos aqu&iacute; para apoyarte.</span></p>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>

                <!--[if mso | IE]>
</td><td style="width:2px;">
<![endif]-->
```

This is the section that contains the image not showing.

Comment: Hello - I don't see any image tags or css background images in your code.  You could try  looking at the Emailify docs for help: https://docs.hypermatic.com/emailify/troubleshooting.html